# PHP - Dynamic number of parameters in function

Tags: php

Let me be more specific than my title. I have this scenario, I was given a grid system that I cannot touch, like:

```
new Row(
  new Column(
    new Subgrid(
      // Row for Header
      new Row(
         new Column(50)
         new Column(50)
      )
      // Rows for content
      new Row(
         new Column()
      )
      new Row(
         new Column()
      )
      // Row for Footer
      new Row(
         new Column()
      )
    )
  )
)
```

A grid in other words where Row, Column and Subgrid are functions. Each of these return an object.

Now, I need to find a way to have the number of some Rows() inside Subgrid to be dynamic. I have a use case where I don't know how many Rows I will have, 2 or 5. How can I implement that?

Till now, I have tried to add all Rows() in an array, simple example:

```
if ($something == true)
$aRows = [
      new Row(
         new Column()
      ),
      new Row(
         new Column()
      )
];
```

or

```
if ($something == true)
$aRows = [
      new Row(
         new Column()
      ),
      new Row(
         new Column()
      ),
      new Row(
         new Column()
      ),
      new Row(
         new Column()
      )
];
```

And then to call that like:

```
new Row(
  new Column(
    new Subgrid(
      // Row for Header
      new Row(
         new Column(50)
         new Column(50)
      )
      // Rows for content
      ...$aRows
      // Row for Footer
      new Row(
         new Column()
      )
    )
  )
)
```

But I simply get Fatal Error "cannot use positional argument after argument unpacking in..."

Comment: _"I have tried to add all Rows() in an array"_ No, you still haven't added all the rows.

Comment: Please share more details, like the code you are using, and the lines that actually throw the given error

Comment: If you cannot change the grid system, and it doesn't accept a variable amount of rows, then it never will.

Comment: Why was my question downvoted? The above questions are not even clear. 
1) you still haven't added all the rows => which rows? it's about making it dynamic anyway
2) Please share more details, like the code you are using -> what kind of code do you need? This is the code I have to work on
3) If you cannot change the grid system, and it doesn't accept a variable amount of rows, then it never will -> ok, I will bite, what do you mean?
I don't get your questions. In the end, it's about how to pass a dynamic number of parameters to a fn()

Comment: You said: _"I was given a grid system that I cannot touch"_, and you didn't share the relevant code. I therefore have to assume you cannot pass it a variable number of parameters. The actual reason I downvoted your question is that the little PHP code you gave is invalid, it looks more like [pseudo-code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348885/is-posting-pseudo-code-in-questions-allowed-on-stack-overflow). For more details see: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please remember that we're here to help you, we're not your adversary. I downvote questions very reluctantly, and only when I am very sure the question cannot reasonably be answered with the information given. I will undo my downvote when you correct your question. Please do not add comments to clarify your question.

Comment: "what kind of code do you need?" - the code that helps to reproduce the problem. Share it, along with the full and exact error message, and add it to your question by editing it (not to the comment section!)

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of, without knowing the class Subgrid.

---

**1.)**

Create the class MySubgrid and extend Subgrid.

**MySubgrid**

```php
class MySubgrid extends Subgrid
{
    public function __construct(...$args)
    {
        $myArgs = [];
        foreach ($args as $arg) {

            if (is_array($arg)) {
                foreach ($arg as $arrayArg) {
                    if ($arrayArg instanceof Row) {
                        $myArgs[] = $arrayArg;
                    }
                }
            }

            if ($arg instanceof Row) {
                $myArgs[] = $arg;
            }
        }
        parent::__construct(...$myArgs);
    }
}
```

**Subgrid**

```php
class Subgrid
{
    public function __construct(...$args)
    {
        // stuff
    }

    // other methods
}
```

**Example with MySubgrid**

```php
new Row(
    new Column(
        new MySubgrid(
            // Row for Header
            new Row(
                new Column(50),
                new Column(50)
            ),
            // Rows for content
            $aRows,
            // Row for Footer
            new Row(
                new Column()
            )
        )
    )
);
```

---

**2.)**

Create an Helper.

**SubgridArgsHelper**

```php
class SubgridArgsHelper
{
    private array $args;

    public function setArgs(array $args): SubgridArgsHelper
    {
        $this->args = array_merge($this->args, $args);
        return $this;
    }

    public function setArg($arg): SubgridArgsHelper
    {
        $this->args[] = $arg;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getArgs(): array
    {
        return $this->args;
    }
}
```

**Example with SubgridArgsHelper**

```php
new Row(
    new Column(
        new Subgrid(
            ...(new SubgridArgsHelper())
                ->setArg(
                    new Row(
                        new Column(50),
                        new Column(50)
                    )
                )
                ->setArgs($aRows)
                ->setArg(
                    new Row(
                        new Column()
                    )
                )
                ->getArgs()

        )
    )
);
```

Comment: I admire your perseverance, but I don't think this will work. You can try a lot, but in the end `Subgrid` needs a given number or arguments, and extending it doesn't change that. We keep coming back to the fact that we don't know anything about the `Subgrid` class, and xmanolis sees it as: "a lot of negativity", when we ask for it. Clearly he's reading something that isn't there, which happens a lot here. Having the grid classes would make it possible for us to give a real answer.